Cannot find module with PAYLOAD 3.0
I do the tutorial " How to Create a Custom Select Field: A Step-by-Step Guide " in payload but I have type errors :
import { SelectInput, useField } from 'payload/components/forms';

Cannot find module 'payload/components/forms' or its corresponding type declarations
OR
import { Field } from 'payload/type';

Cannot find module 'payload/type' or its corresponding type declarations
I searched the forums and I think it's a version problem.
"dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.673.0",
    "@aws-sdk/lib-storage": "^3.673.0",
    "@payloadcms/db-mongodb": "3.0.0-beta.108",
    "@payloadcms/db-postgres": "3.0.0-beta.108",
    "@payloadcms/next": "3.0.0-beta.108",
    "@payloadcms/richtext-lexical": "3.0.0-beta.108",
    "@payloadcms/richtext-slate": "3.0.0-beta.108",
    "@payloadcms/storage-s3": "3.0.0-beta.108",
    "@payloadcms/ui": "3.0.0-beta.108",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.1.0",
    "aws-crt": "^1.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-react-compiler": "0.0.0-experimental-48eb8f4-20240822",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "clsx": "^2.1.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "date-fns": "^4.1.0",
    "embla-carousel-react": "^8.3.0",
    "graphql": "^16.8.2",
    "lucide-react": "^0.451.0",
    "next": "15.0.0-canary.160",
    "payload": "3.0.0-beta.108",
    "react": "19.0.0-rc-e740d4b1-20240919",
    "react-dom": "19.0.0-rc-e740d4b1-20240919",
    "shadcn-ui": "^0.9.2",
    "sharp": "^0.33.5",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.5.3",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7"

I wanted to download the more advanced version of payload but I had dependency problems.
Have you ever had this problem ? Can you help me? Thank you very much!

Well, if you command npm install payload, then u will get the latest version of it and it is automatically added to the dependencies in your package.json file...

The tutorials haven't been updated to work with Payload 3.0 yet.
The main breaking changes you will run into here is that all the exports from payload and it's various packages now export from the root of each package.
Your editor will likely know where to import from if you remove the import lines and then try to fix the missing variables.
Aside from imports, there was a breaking change in how custom components are imported as path strings instead of importing the component directly in the config. Read more in the breaking changes of the release notes.

Thank you :)  I looked and  for import { SelectInput, useField } from '@payloadcms/ui' and  and for import { Field } from 'payload', it's ok :)
